# Script to search for files and rename files

Tags: windows, scripting, file-rename

I have about 11000 different files in hundreds different folders, sub folders and sub-sub folders in following location `\\mastercorrespondence`, and I need to rename some of the files and copy corresponding file from `K:\CDS_TOOL_MANUAL_OVERRIDES` daily in their own subfolder.

In short it should perform following steps

1. Look for any PDF format documents in `K:\ CDS_TOOL_MANUAL_OVERRIDES` folder.
2. For each document in  `K:\ CDS_TOOL_MANUAL_OVERRIDES`  look for PDF document with identical file name held in the `\\mastercorrespondence”` any sub-directory.
3. If corresponding file found then rename file in `\\mastercorrespondence` sub-directory as `<Original Filename>_<Overwritten>_<dd.mm.yy>`
4. Move the file from `K:\ CDS_TOOL_MANUAL_OVERRIDES` folder to the same location as it counterpart in the `\\10.5.13.10\mastercorrespondence` sub-directory.
5. If any documents did not have a corresponding file in `\\mastercorrespondence` sub-directory then write a message to log file stating names of unmatched files.

Folder Structure is Like.

```
\\mastercorrespondence\SIPP\21\201201\01
\\mastercorrespondence\SIPP\21\2012022
\\mastercorrespondence\ISA\10201201\201202\02
\\mastercorrespondence\ISA\10201201\201203
\\mastercorrespondence\ISA\10201201\201204
\\mastercorrespondence\ISA\10201201\201205
```

Comment: `dd.mm.yy`, really? Why not use a sane date format that works well with file names, such as `yyyy-mm-dd`? And what did you try so far?

Comment: @Joey not really fussed about the dateformat anything will do. So far tried this bit.




 Path = "\\mastercorrespondence"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Sub visitFolder(folderVar)
    For Each fileToRename In folderVar.Files
        fileToRename.Name = "Overwritten " & fileToRename.Name
    Next
    For Each folderToVisit In folderVar.SubFolders
        visitFolder(folderToVisit)
    Next
End Sub

If FSO.FolderExists(Path) Then
    visitFolder(FSO.getFolder(Path))
End If

Comment: Edit your question to include what you have already tried and where you hit problems (code in comments doesn't read as well). We're not here to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a starting point in PowerShell, if that works for you:

```
#Look for any PDF format documents in K:\ CDS_TOOL_MANUAL_OVERRIDES folder.
$pdfFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path K:\CDS_TOOL_MANUAL_OVERRIDES -filter "*.pdf"

#For each document in K:\ CDS_TOOL_MANUAL_OVERRIDES look for PDF document with identical file name held in the \\mastercorrespondence” any sub-directory.
$referenceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path \\mastercorrespondence -recurse -filter "*.pdf"
$pdfFiles | %{
    $_ = $pdfFile
    $matched = ""
    #I don't fully understand what you're asking for, but it seems to me that the move and rename are on the same file, and technically a rename is a move... so I've combined them.
    $referenceFiles | %{if ($_.Name -eq $pdfFile.Name) {$matched = $_}  }
    if ($matched -ne "") {
        $destinationName = ($pdfFile.Name + "_OverWritten_"+(Get-Date -format dd.MM.yy))
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination ($matched.DirectoryName + "\" + $destinationName)
    }
    else{
        #If any documents did not have a corresponding file in \\mastercorrespondence sub-directory then write a message to log file stating names of unmatched files.
        ("Unable to locate matching file: " + $pdfFile.FullName) | Out-File -Append -FilePath "K:\mover.log"
    }
}
```